# convert javascript date format to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, date

how to convert default date in javascript to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format.

new Date() returns Sun Aug 07 2016 16:38:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)

and i need the current date to above format.

Comment: You have `dateobj.getFullYear()`, `dateobj.getMonth()`, `dateobj.getDate()`, `dateobj.getHours()`, `dateobj.getMinutes()`, `dateobj.getSeconds()`. Easy, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Your format assumes local, how will others know the offset?

Answer (score 13):

As `new Date().toISOString()` will return current UTC time, to get local time in ISO String format we have to get time from `new Date()` function like the following method

```js
document.write(new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0]);
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it doesn't require any third party libraries. It sucks that JS doesn't have a cleaner option though.

Comment: This is the best answer I have found. It's very useful when your API accept that data format. You use it that way: new Date(YourDate.toString().split('GMT')[0] + ' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0] (second new Date() replace with your variable :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to achieve this.

Try:

```
var moment = require('moment')
let dateNow = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS')
```

Comment: I know this was posted a while back but the format should be 'YYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss  otherwise you will get month value for minutes and fractional seconds to two digits for actual seconds

Answer (score 5):

This could work :

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 2):

For use the date in **ISO 8601 format** run the command lines below on NodeJS console or on browser console:

```
$ node
> var today = new Date(); // or
> var today = new Date(2016, 8, 7, 14, 06, 30); // or
> var today = new Date('2016-08-07T14:06:30');
> today; // Show the date in standard USA format. Grrrr!
> today.toISOString();
```

For more information, consult the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: *toISOString* uses UTC, the OP seems to not want the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

moment is to large, you can use fecha

```js
import fecha from 'fecha'

const uTime ="2019-10-21T18:57:33"

fecha.format(fecha.parse(uTime, "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss"), 'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm:ss')

// console.log(2019.10.21 18:57:33)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to explain your answer a little bit. In this case, there are some more replies so you should expose Cons and Pros of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let date = new Date(Date.now());
date = now.toISOString().substr(0,now.toISOString().indexOf("."));
```

//2021-07-26T09:07:59

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : **it is not recommended** to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

`new Date(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[0]+' UTC').toISOString().split('.')[0]);`

Comment: Try to explain your answer a little bit.